# Ternary or terser setClass equivalent

Tags: jquery, ternary-operator

We have addClass, removeClass, toggleClass

What is the jQuery equivalent to

```
document.getElementById("field").className=(someBoolean)?"pass":"fail";
```

but using one of the methods that **leave existing classes** in place?

The closest I have come is the in my opinion not so elegant

```
$("#field")
  .toggleClass("pass",someBoolean)
  .toggleClass("fail",!someBoolean);
```

Or using vars

```
$("#field")
  .toggleClass(classWhenTrue,someBoolean)
  .toggleClass(classWhenFalse,!someBoolean);
```

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  var pass = true;

    $("#field")
    .toggleClass("pass", pass)
    .toggleClass("fail", !pass);
    var classes = [...$("#field").get(0).classList];
    console.log(classes)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field" type="text" class="test fail done" />
```

Comment: Why is the double `toggleClass` not so elegant? It's a lot more readable than any of the answers you've gotten...

Comment: This is a 5 year old question. I was likely just curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
$("#field").removeClass('pass fail').addClass(someBoolean ? 'pass' : 'fail');
```

Comment: Closer :) let's see if anyone else has a suggestion, yours is the best so far

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.

```
$('#field').attr('class', someBoolean ? 'pass' : 'fail');
```

`.attr('class', 'newClass')` is the equivalent to `element.className = 'newClass';`

Comment: I know I can do that, but that replaces the class. As I mentioned I want to be able to have other classes in the class attribute, which is what addClass, removeClass and toggleClass respects

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

`$('.submit-button')[ someBoolean ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]('active')`

Comment: @mplungjan its the job of the asker of the question to create an MCVE so that people can find it easier to answer the question

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Done

Comment: It does not work as I surmised. `$("#field")[ pass ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]('pass') ` will not toggle both classes